# Ionic - Session Expiry remembering last page for a few seconds?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, token, ionic4

The token for my application is set to expire after 30 minutes and I have the 401/403 error setup like this:

```
// 401 or 403 error
async unauthorisedError() {
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
  header: 'Session has expired',
  message: 'Click OK to login again',
  buttons: [
    {
    text: 'OK',
    role: 'cancel',
    cssClass: 'secondary',
    handler: close => {
      console.log('close unauthorized');
      this.storage.clear();
      this.authenticationService.login();
      this.open = false;
       // do nothing else
    }
  }
]
 });

alert.present();
}
```

So my app is redirected back to the login page in order for them to login again and once theyve logged in theyre redirected straight to the homepage (well should be).

For some reason when the user logs back in again it is reverting to the screen it was on before it timed out for 1/2/3 seconds and then redirecting to the homepage.

Does anyone know how I can stop this reverting back to the page it expired on for a few seconds or is this just the code running and trying to catchup with itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do pretty much the same in an application, we have an interceptor and if the code is `401` or `403` we redirect the user back to the login page. You can show your message there, and you shouldn't have this "memory" issue anymore

Comment: So if i add  this.router.navigate(['/tabs/main-page']); //POINT TO HOME before the this.authenticationService.login() then that means it goes to the home screen before login and then once logged back in it will go to the homescreen? going to test that out thanks! does my logic match what you were thinking

Comment: How do you do your login? do you have a specific page for that? is it a modal?

Comment: yeah its an external login that we use, so I use a themeble browser to display that and then once authenticated then the home screen shows of my app

Comment: Yeah so probably it is a good idea to redirect the user to the ```main-page``` when they're "kicked out" of the system and then do the login.

Comment: no problem going to test it out now and let you know - I will upvote if it works :)